# Basic for loop over string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is something that has been killing me for an hour. I'm trying to do a simple for loop over a string, and return the current character and the next character.

```
var mystring = "abcdef";

for (x in mystring) {
   if (mystring[x + 1]) {
      console.log(x + ": " + mystring[x] + mystring[x + 1]);
   }
   else {
      console.log("You've reached the end of the string");
   }
}
```

In every iteration of the loop, "mystring[x + 1]" is false. Though I would expect it to be true for the first five characters of the string. What is going on here? Is there something about JavaScript that I do not understand?

Comment: Should be reported for abuse of *for..in*…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 8):

`for-in` is for looping over the *names of enumerable properties of an object*. The property names are always strings*. `string + number` results in a string, using concatenation (e.g., `"1" + 1` is `"11"`, not `2`).

So if you converted the property name to a number first, it might mostly work:

```
x = +x; // Convert to number
if (mystring[x + 1]) {
```

...but I would use

```
for (x = 0; x < mystring.length; ++x) {
```

...instead. If I needed to support old browsers, I'd also use `.charAt(...)` rather than `[...]` to get the character (but I think the browsers that didn't support indexing into strings are pretty dead these days).

Live example with just the `x = +x`:

```js
var mystring = "abcdef";

for (x in mystring) {
   x = +x;
   if (mystring[x + 1]) {
      snippet.log(x + ": " + mystring[x] + mystring[x + 1]);
   }
   else {
      snippet.log("You've reached the end of the string");
   }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

* *"property names are always strings"* That's true in ES5. In ES6+, they might also be `Symbol` instances, but `for-in` doesn't visit the ones that aren't strings. That's not relevant here, but I hate to leave a statement like that out there... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Something so obvious. Guess I just needed another pair of eyes!

Comment: @user3892126: I wouldn't call it obvious. :-) Have fun,